# Filtering fields to be returned in API response

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have a very simple question. Given the following code:

```py
import requests, json, pprint
from pprint import pprint

api_key='<mykey>'  #define API key
movie_title='The Godfather'  # define title
url = f'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key={api_key}&query={movie_title}'
results=requests.get(url)
j = results.json()
pprint(j)
```

I am getting more information in the results than I need:

```json
{'page': 1,
 'results': [{'adult': False,
              'backdrop_path': '/rSPw7tgCH9c6NqICZef4kZjFOQ5.jpg',
              'genre_ids': [18, 80],
              'id': 238,
              'original_language': 'en',
              'original_title': 'The Godfather',
              'overview': 'Spanning the years 1945 to 1955, a chronicle of the '....
```

Is there a way in Python to only return data from a few of the fields that I need? For example, to only get back data for `id`, `original_title`, and `release_date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
# As a result you've got a json response
# It is a python dictionary (a KEY-VALUE pairs of data)
# Python dictionary is within curly braces {}
# To get out a value from dictionary you need to refer to a key 

myDict = {"Name": "Bob", "Age": 32, "Gender": "Male"}
print('My name is ' + myDict["Name"] + ', I am ' + str(myDict["Age"]) + ' years old and my gender is ' + myDict["Gender"] + '.')

# it will be printed:
#       My name is Bob, I am 32 years old and my gender is Male.

# Within your (incomplete) result there  is a list too
# A list is an array of values - the values are  indexed starting with 0
# If you want to get out the third letter from a list (C)

myList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
print(myList[2])

# it will be printed:
#       C

# Your result
j = {'page': 1, 'results': [{'adult': False, 'backdrop_path': '/rSPw7tgCH9c6NqICZef4kZjFOQ5.jpg', 'genre_ids': [18, 80], 'id': 238, 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'The Godfather'}]}

# If you need the id then you can see that it is within the key "results" whose value is a list [] of dictionaries [{}]. ID is in the first element of the list and it's KEY is "id"
# To get it
print(j["results"][0]["id"])
# it will be printed:
#       238

print(j["results"][0]["original_title"])
# it will be printed:
#       The Godfather

# Try to read it from right to left like this 
#       Give me the value of KEY "original_title" - from the first element in list which (list) is the value of KEY "results" in the response
# Or from left to right
#       There is a KEY "results" holding a list in whose first member is another dictionary holding a name of the movie under the KEY "original_title" - get me that title
```

Dictionaries and lists could be iterated and you can use it to get whatever you want.
I don't know the complete or exact structure of data you have got as a response but if it is something like below (and probably it is) then you can
define your own list of key data that you need and get out whatever you want.
In this sample the selected data for each movie will be printed out.

```py
myMoviesList = []
myListOfKeys = ["id", "original_language", "original_title"]
j = [
        {'page': 1, 'results': 
            [
                {'adult': False, 'genre_ids': [18, 80], 'id': 238, 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'The Godfather'},
                {'adult': False, 'genre_ids': [21, 65], 'id': 239, 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'The Dune'},
                {'adult': False, 'genre_ids': [21, 65], 'id': 240, 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'The Taxi Driver'},
                {'adult': False, 'genre_ids': [18, 80], 'id': 241, 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'The Deer Hunter'}
            ]
        },
        {'page': 2, 'results': 
            [
                {'adult': False, 'genre_ids': [18, 80], 'id': 242, 'original_language': 'es', 'original_title': 'Kika'},
                {'adult': False, 'genre_ids': [18, 80], 'id': 243, 'original_language': 'es', 'original_title': 'Los Amantes del Circulo Polar'},
                {'adult': False, 'genre_ids': [18, 80], 'id': 244, 'original_language': 'es', 'original_title': 'Hable con Ella'},
                {'adult': False, 'genre_ids': [21, 65], 'id': 245, 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'The Room in Rome'}
            ]        
        }       
    ]
    
for i in range(len(j)):
    pg = j[i]["page"]
    for dct in(j[i]["results"]):
        myPageDct = {}
        for key, val in dct.items():
            if key in(myListOfKeys):
                myPageDct[key] = val
        myMoviesList.append(myPageDct)
        
        print(myPageDct)
'''
Print Out Result
{'id': 238, 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'The Godfather'}
{'id': 239, 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'The Dune'}
{'id': 240, 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'The Taxi Driver'}
{'id': 241, 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'The Deer Hunter'}
{'id': 242, 'original_language': 'es', 'original_title': 'Kika'}
{'id': 243, 'original_language': 'es', 'original_title': 'Los Amantes del Circulo Polar'}
{'id': 244, 'original_language': 'es', 'original_title': 'Hable con Ella'}
{'id': 245, 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'The Room in Rome'}
'''
```

All the dictionaries are collected into one variable myMoviesList which is a list of dictionaries.
**This way you can change the resulting data simply by changing the myListOfKeys variable** if needed in the future.
For start you can see more about dictionaries at https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp and lists at https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp
Regards...